# How to create a common AsyncTask class for webservice call in an android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, design-patterns, android-asynctask, webservices-client

I am trying to write a common webservice class where in any of the activities within my application has to point to this common class for webservice stuff.
Currently I got stuck in between i.e; to pass the success/failure message to the calling class,
My current implementation is like below,
I have an interface class where in I have 2 methods,

```
 public void webServiceReqExecutedSuccessfully();
 public void webSerReqFailed();
```

and each webservice calling class implements these methods as per their requirements.
And my common webservice class is like below,

```
    public class WebServiceRequest extends AsyncTask < String, Void, Boolean> 
    {             
        private static final MediaType FORM_DATA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");                          public enum HTTPServiceTags {             
          POST_IT,
          GET_ALL_ITEMS
         }

         HTTPServiceTags requestTag;
         public ATWebServiceRequest(HTTPServiceTags reqTag, Callable < Void > _ServiceResponseSuccess, Callable < Void > _ServiceResponseFailure) {
          this.requestTag = reqTag;
         }

         @Override
         protected Boolean doInBackground(String...postDataSet) {
          Boolean result = true;
          String requestURL = postDataSet[0];
          String postBody = getPostBody(postDataSet);
          Log.d(requestURL, postBody);
          try {
           OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
           RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(FORM_DATA_TYPE, postBody);
           Request request = new Request.Builder().url(requestURL).post(body).build();
           Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
          } catch (IOException exception) {
           result = false;
          }
          return result;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
          if (result) {
           switch (requestTag) {
            case POST_IT:
//HOW CAN I NOTIFY/INVOKE webServiceReqExecutedSuccessfully METHOD OF THE CALLING CLASS HERE??? 
             break;
            case GET_ALL_ITEMS:
             break;
            default:
             break;
           }
          }
         }
        }
```

My question here is after the service call response how can I notify/invoke the calling class interface methods(webServiceReqExecutedSuccessfully() / webSerReqFailed()) from which object reference?
Any help is appreciated in advance. Thanks

Comment: Use Interface as a callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `Interface` which will be use as callback.

```
public interface MyCallBack {
    void onResult(HTTPServiceTags requestTag);
}
```

In your `Activity` implements that interface-

```
public class Xyz extends Activity implements MyCallBack {

  @override
  public void void onResult(HTTPServiceTags requestTag) {
  // Do your work
  }
}
```

Pass that interface in your AsyncTask's constructor-

```
public WebServiceRequest(MyCallBack callBack) {
   this.mCallBack = callBack; // Assign it to global variable
}
```

Then in `onPostExecute` call it -

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
   if (result) {
   mCallBack.onResult(requestTag);
  }
}
```